# Array offset through end

Tags: c#

In C++ I could use pointer arithmetic to grab everything from a start position to the end of an array. What do you do in C# to accomplish the same thing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string GetText(byte[] value, uint startPos)
        {
            // TODO - What goes here?
            return "";
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] value = new byte[] { 0x41, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42 };
            string result = GetText(value, 1);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Expecting output:
BBB

Comment: You would never get "BBB" in c++.  You would get "ABBB".

Comment: `.Length` - 1 will give you the last indexed value in an array. So if you are trying to convert bytes to characters and append it to a string, you could use a `for loop` starting at uint startPos and loop until `value.Length - 1`

Comment: @jdweng he wants to skip the characters until index is startPos, in this case 1, skipping the A

Comment: Do you expect the 1 to refer to a byte offset, or a character offset? They may very well be different.

Comment: In general, you might want to become familiar with LINQ, which has methods like `Skip` and `ToArray()` and `ToList()`. In this case : `value.Skip(startPos)` would return an enumerable of bytes from `startPos` to the end, then you would use standard byte-to-text conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string result =System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value);
return result.Substring(startPos,result.Length-startPos);
```

(check that startPos is within 0 and length-1)

Or with [GetString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_Encoding_GetString_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_)

```
return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value, startPos, startPos-value.Length);
```

Comment: you can also use the `GetString` override that accepts `index` and `count` arguments

Comment: Point made, edited.

Comment: startPos-value.Length looks backwards, but I get the point.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can achieve what you need with

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string GetText(byte[] value, int startPos)
        {
            if(startPos >= 0 && startPos <= value.Length)
            {
               return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value).Substring(startPos);
            }
            else
            {
               return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] value = new byte[] { 0x41, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42 };
            string result = GetText(value, 1);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```